# How do I keep the .stl files from being resized while exporting?

Tags: cad, stl

I made a few models in Autodesk Inventor. When I tried to get them printed, the printer created a model smaller than the model I made in Inventor (270mm x 200mm). Is there a way to keep them from getting resized?

Here is the model in Inventor:
[image: The model in Autodesk Inventor]
And here is the model being visualized by the printer driver:
[image: The model being visualized by the printer driver]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: Luckily, it doesn't matter, since all slicing programs allow you to scale the dimensions.  So long as you know at least one edge-to-edge dimension, you can handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## .stl Basics

The .stl format has no inherent sense of which units you use. items are to scale to an ambiguous 1, which could be 1 meter, one millimeter, one lightyear or one inch. To a .stl, only the *relative* sizing matters. All these faces you see are compared to a line with the length of 1-unit that is

## Slicer-Modeling Software interaction

The most common graphic design programs export in millimeters, but some US ones just assume inches, which is a factor of 1"=25.4mm.

Cura, Netfabb, and Slic3r expect that the 1-unit line is one **millimeter** long - but if it is an inch instead, then the model is shrunk by 1/25.4 or to about 4% of the right size. Scaling up by 2540% one would return to the millimeter scale.

But then there are other programs that use other choices of scales. [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing) for example assumes a scene is in meters by default.

## Inventor

Inventor can export .stl in a variety of scales, which all just serve as how the length of the inherent but invisible 1-unit line is drawn. The default choice is **centimeters**, so a scaling factor of 1cm=10mm, which would explain the models being only 1/10th of the expected size in Slic3r. to change the scaling, follow the [manual](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2014/ENU/Inventor/files/GUID-59FB702C-F37A-4DEA-ADCF-51AD8A219C9B-htm.html):

- upon exporting a .stl, click `Options`
- under Units, choose `mm`

Comment: From the images he added, the model length and width are in the 100s.

Comment: @PerplexedDipole his *other* picture shows about 2 division lines on a prusa bed on an edge that should be 200mm. 20mm instead of 200mm is what factor? 1/10th.