# Cura deleting parts of model

Tags: ultimaker-cura

So the base model isn't mine, I just added hair and stuff. I'm new to Blender and 3D printing so bear with me, please.

So this is the model before slicing:

[image: Screenshot of a 3D model in Cura]

And this is after:

[image: Screenshot of a Cura's Preview of a 3D model]

I tried changing the size of the model, supports, and quality but nothing makes a difference. So I check the model on Blender and see the eye plate is thin and the head is hollow:

[image: Screenshot of 3D model in Blender]

[image: Screenshot of the same 3D model in Blender with modifications]

So I thought that might be the problem. So I tried to replace the thin eye plate with a ball (I don't like how it looks at all but I have no idea what else to do) But then I encounter this problem from slicing:

[image: Screenshot of a Cura's Preview of the 3D model but with parts missing]

I've run out of ideas as I just don't have enough experience or knowledge with Blender etc. I'd really love to be able to print it with the original eyes if possible, and honestly don't really see why it'd be an issue printing as is anyway since the printer fills the insides and has plenty of support, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for handling units for 3D printing with Blender](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19162/best-practices-for-handling-units-for-3d-printing-with-blender) or https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15868/cura-messes-up-my-print-how-can-i-make-it-print-what-i-see-in-blender/ or

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out so thought I'd share it with anyone with a similar problem.

I used the solidify mod on the eye plate and made it thicker. Then it appeared fine when slicing but the head had a similar problem as my last photo. So, with a joined sphere inside, I did the same thing (solidify and make it thicker), and now it's perfect! :) Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Without seeing the "eye-plate" completely I guess that the model was not "solid" and "waterproof" and just a bent plane. A printable model must have thickness, so a single plane is not printable. "Solidify" makes flat planes thicker and thus printable. The 3DSmax modifier "Shell" does the same thing. Good you solved it yourself!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer. You can always change the accepted answer later should a better answer come along; Thanks.